# difference between C/C++Build / Settings / Includes and C/C++General / Path and Symbols / Includes?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse I've found two pages in Project Properties:

- C/C++Build / Settings / Includes
- C/C++General / Path and Symbols / Includes

It seems in both cases I can specify Include folders. What is the difference between these two options?